# How to tune wi-fi router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, skype

I'm using THOMSON TCW710 and the internet through wifi lags from time to time. HTTP sometimes hangs, but generally bearable. What's worse, skype on my laptop doesn't work at all. It starts working when connecting to the router directly with LAN. It also works with another wifi connection. I can access router setup page, please help understanding what should I tweak or should I just throw it out.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the basics:

- Check if the link quality is sufficiently high
- Check what the link speed is. If it is really low, it's a sign of interference or a bad signal

If the link quality or speed is bad, try moving the device to a location closer to the router or move the router closer to your device. An increased distance is bad for wifi signal. Also, try not to have any walls in between if possible.

Regardless of the outcome, I'd also try the following things:

- Use software like Inssider to scan the environment for other networks. Note the channels that other networks are using and try to change your channel to a free one. On 2.4GHz wifi this means that you should leave four channels between yours and another to avoid interference. Typically, it is advised to only use 1, 6 and 11.
- Update your wireless card's drivers
- Update your router's firmware

If that doesn't work, I'd recommend you install a wireless access point closer to your device. If there are a lot of other networks on the 2.4GHz band closeby then I'd strongly recommend to get a 802.11AC access point and wireless card to take advantage of the 5GHz band which is generally less congested and doesn't penetrate walls easily. This is a downside as you're likely to need more access points to cover your house but it's also a big plus because your neighbours are less likely to caue interference.

Answer (score 1):

The wireless gateway you are using only supports 802.11 b/g. Unfortunately that means you are using a very old technology on a completely saturated wireless band (2.4Ghz).

As mentioned in another answer, the 2.4Ghz channel has only 11 channels (a couple more in some countries) but only 3 that don’t overlap (1, 6, 11). In addition, new “automatic” channel selection features of nearby routers cause them to use any number of channels between 1-11 even though it is imperative that all nearby WiFi signals cooperate with each other and utilize only channels 1, 6, 11. So, if you are in any moderately populated area, there is a good chance that there are several nearby wireless networks stomping all over you. In my home, 2.4Ghz is unusable, even if I stand right next to my access point. There are no less than 20 other nearby 2.4Ghz networks from a nearby apartment.

Unfortunately, your router doesn’t have any other modern technology to use. The long term solution would be to update your equipment to support the 5Ghz band with a minimum of Wireless N. The 5Ghz band has 23 channels and none of them overlap at a 20Mhz bandwidth. Therefore, even if you use the same channel as a nearby network, they will cooperate.

Your only other option is to try some of the suggestions in the another answer to identify nearby networks and what channels they use and try to find the cleanest channel, as well as relocating equipment in your home.